# how to create url like example.com/account in gwt application

Tags: url, gwt, subdomain

I need to create a few urls which for my gwt application. e.g currently login screen is

http://127.0.0.1:8888/abc.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
http://example.com/abc.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

i want to change it to

http://127.0.0.1:8888/accounts
http://example.com/accounts

so when user directly open this link

I have developed this applicatoin in gwt with jdbc

looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at how GWT handles [History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). You can save states of your application by using History tokens(For ex: ../modulename#user1, ../modulename#user2) and by parsing these tokens you can direct your user to appropriate section of your application. Since GWT applications run on a single html page I beleive this would be the correct approach to implement your functionality. Last but not least these states are bookmarkable and supports browsers back button as well.

By the way about changing the Url, ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 is added to the url in development mode and will not appear in production mode when you compile deploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subfolder named `accounts` and move the index.html file there. The webserver should not automatically serve the index.html file, when someone requests to see the folder.

Comment: but i want it to be automated, and for different modules of the application, different urls, and also how will handle the requests coming from client on http://www.example.com ?

Comment: or take another example, each username has his url. e.g www.example.com/meuser1 and www.example.com/johnsmith

Comment: GWT itself cannot do you anything good here. You have to either use the Java mechanisms for that (web.xml) or if you have an Apache use a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the history and add the token in them:

```
private static final String abc = "account";
History.newItem(abc ,true);
```